# Unable to system.exit within a try section

Tags: python

I'm trying to port an existing Java program I have. I have the following `try` section:

```
try:
    quote = getValue(i)
    writeData(i,quote)
except:
    print("Oops!", sys.exc_info()[0], "occurred.")
```

Within the `getValue(value)` function, under some conditions I want to exit the program:

```
sys.exit()
```

However, the `except` clause intercepts also this kind of error:

```
Oops! <class 'SystemExit'> occurred.
```

From my Java background a `System.exit()` forces the termination of the program. What is the simplest way in Python to force exiting the program, even with an `except` clause?

Comment: Don't ever ever use bare `except`

Comment: What is `getValue`?

Comment: switch to `except Exception` and it won't happen (but don't ever do that either; you shouldn't be writing code that catches exceptions you don't explicitly expect and know how to handle).

Comment: I disagree a little bit with @Charles in the sense that it's OK to use something like `except Exception as exc:` as long as the exception isn't simply ignored — and printing out an error message satisfies that requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.exit` just raises a `SystemExit` exception, which is a subclass of `BaseException` but not `Exception`.

```
>>> issubclass(SystemExit, Exception)
False
>>> issubclass(SystemExit, BaseException)
True
>>> issubclass(Exception, BaseException)
True
```

A base `except` catches *all* exceptions, equivalent to `except BaseException`, which is why you virtually never want to use a bare `except`. Use `except Exception` to only catch error-like exceptions, not flow-control exceptions as well.

```
try:
    quote = getValue(i)
    writeData(i,quote)
except Exception:
    print("Oops!", sys.exc_info()[0], "occurred.")
```

As a general rule, you want to limit your `except` clauses as much as possible. When doing something as broad as `except Exception`, you usually want to exit your program or re-raise the exception, not treat it as handled just by logging it.

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the `SystemException` and use the value to call `sys.exit()` again:

```
import sys

try:
    sys.exit(1)
except SystemExit as e:
    sys.exit(e.code)
```

Comment: Why do that instead of just changing `except:` to `except Exception:`? (`SystemExit` is not an `Exception`)

Comment: As I understand the question, the normal `Exception` has nothing to do with closing the application. So if `writeData` writes to a Database the Excpetion to be thrown is a `DatabaseError`. But if the data contains some value, perhaps the application should be closed. Also my answer is incomplete as the default `exception` branch is missing

Comment: @Cereaubra, see chepner's answer -- the "default exception branch" catches _more_ than just `Exception`s, which is why it's (unintentionally) also catching `SystemExit`s.

Answer (score 1):

The `sys.exit()` call does [nothing more](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c590b581bba517f81ced2e6f531ccc9e2e22eab5/Python/sysmodule.c#L853-L860) than raises a `SystemExit` exception. You are catching this.

You can handle that exception specifically and reraise it:

```py
try:
    quote = getValue(i)
    writeData(i,quote)
except SystemExit:
    raise
except:
    print("Oops!", sys.exc_info()[0], "occurred.")
```